# Python: How to create new variables in for loops?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create several arrays in a loop and have access to them further on. I don't understand why I can modify and print them within the loop but outside it says the variable doesn't exist.

```
for i in range (0,3):
    a_i=[i]
    a_i.append(i+1)
    print a_i
print a_1
```

Is there anyone who can give me a suggestion on how to fix the problem?

Comment: Have a read through http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)

Comment: You have not defined `a_1`, only `a_i`.

Comment: There's no reason to downvote someone because their code is wrong. Their code being wrong is why they're asking the question.

Comment: @flabons Welcome to StackOverflow! Let me inform you that [is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stack-overflow-a-forum), it's a Q&A site. If you want to discuss an answer, use "add comment". If you want to provide additional details, edit your question, we'll notice. Only use "Answer" when you're providing a solution to a question.

Answer (score 8):

Variables name are tokens used as-is, i.e. variables aren't expanded inside other variable names.

You can't expect `a_i` to be equal to `a_1` if `i == 1`.

For that, use arrays or dictionaries.

```
a = {}
for i in range (0,3):
    a[i] = [i]
    a[i].append(i+1)
    print a[i]
print a
print a[1]
```